# Problems with authentification on proxy cntlm Ubuntu 18.4 server

Tags: apt, proxy

I've just installed ubuntu 18.4 on my server. As we are behind a firewall so I need a proxy. Linux and my company's proxy do not work together, therefore I've installed cntlm on one computer. This service has a proper authentification on our companies proxy. Then I tried to get this cntlm-proxy from my server.

Let's say User= MyUser, Password = MyPassword, Domain is MyDomain.  172.24.213.55 is the comuter with cntlm service.

In `bash.bashrc` I've added following lines:

```
    #set proxy
function setproxy(){
export {http,https,ftp}_proxy="http://MyDomain\\MyUser:MyPassword@172.24.213.55:3128/"

 }

#unset proxy
function unsetproxy() {
unset {http,https,ftp}_proxy
}
```

I reboot and then run setproxy. But when I then run sudo apt-get update,

I get

```
407 Proxy Authentification Required [IP: 172.24.213.55 3128].
```

As a newbe, I cannot find the reason. I changed `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (here with `acquire::http::proxy`), `95proxies` and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy with CNTLM authentication, you need to properly configure CNTLM daemon.

First set the proper domain and username in the `/etc/cntlm.conf`file:

```
#
# Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration
#
# NOTE: all values are parsed literally, do NOT escape spaces,
# do not quote. Use 0600 perms if you use plaintext password.
#

Username      domainusername
Domain          domainname

# List of parent proxies to use. More proxies can be defined
# one per line in format <proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
Proxy           123.123.123.123:1234
```

Then run `cntlm -H` and enter your domain password:

```
$ cntlm -H
Password: 
PassLM          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PassNT          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PassNTLMv2      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    # Only for user ' domainusername ', domain ' domainname '
```

Add the output (from PassLM to PassNTLMv2) to the `/etc/cntlm.conf` file and restart the CNTLM daemon.

Then you can add `export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128` to your bash configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. With no connection to the internet as such I tried to use the cntlm service running on my windows client and trying to address this Service from my ubuntu server. This did not work. I did download the cntlm somewhere else and then installed it directly on the ubuntu server. Using your explanation, and after rebooting the system it finaly worked.